# Python: change json data according to provided paths (e.g. jsonpath)

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I need a tool to modify json data with some arbitrary function applied only to specific paths expressed in some syntax (e.g. jsonpath, but may be any other). Key feature is to **modify existing data structure**, not to extract only some piece and then modify it.
Is there something like I described?

For example we got the input data:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "group": "Admins", 
      "name": "John Smith"
    }, 
    {
      "group": "Users", 
      "name": "James Taylor"
    }
  ], 
  "groups": [ "Admins", "Users" ]
}
```

and I want to drop users' last names. So, I need to apply the function like
`lambda x: x.split(' ')[0]` to the jsonpath like
`$.users..name`

as a result I want to get

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "group": "Admins", 
      "name": "John"
    }, 
    {
      "group": "Users", 
      "name": "James"
    }
  ], 
  "groups": [ "Admins", "Users" ]
}
```

This is a very simple example, input data and path expression may be more sophisticated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution using **jsonpath-ng**.

```
from jsonpath_ng import parse
input_data = json.load(file_with_json)
path = '$.users..name'
findings = parse(path).find(input_data)
for finding in findings:
    some_new_value = finding.value.split(' ')[0]
    finding.full_path.update(input_data, some_new_value)
```

As a result *input_data* will contain an original dictionary but with updated values finded by *path*

Comment: For some unknown reason, I had to wrap my `input_data` in a list:
`finding.full_path.update([input_data], some_new_value)`